# How to make Wordforms handle three related words?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, synonym

I'm trying to create synonym relationships between 3 similar words

cesarian > luscs
caesarian > cesarian
caesarian > luscs

but if I try this I get this when trying to index

WARNING: duplicate wordform found - skipped ( current='caesarian > luscs',
stored='caesarian > cesarian' ). Fix your wordforms file 'lib/wordforms.txt'

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try it with just two of those (so each word is covered at least once).

Comment: Thanks Pat. There are actually three different words there. Caesarian, cesarian, and luscs. There are plenty of situations thought where many terms match many synonym terms, so there must be a way for wordforms to handle it.

Comment: (Right, don't press enter). Essentially, what you're wanting to do is `cesarian > caesarian > luscs` - so break that out over two lines (`cesarian > caesarian` and `caesarian > luscs`) and see if Sphinx is smart enough to follow the mappings from one to the other. Otherwise, maybe switch the last of your three listed in the question around - `luscs > caesarian`? That way, all three words on the left are different.

Comment: luscs > cesarian<br>
caesarian > cesarian<br>
cesarian > luscs<br> would make sense.<br>  caesarian > cesarian only works one way however.  Maybe when that problem is solved...